# Does anyone have experience with Windows SyncToy?

Tags: windows, synchronization

[SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/prophoto/downloads/synctoybeta.aspx)

Does it work?  Is it worth using?  Any gotchas I should be aware of?  Is it "enterprise grade"?

I just stumbled across it today. If it works as advertised, this would solve quite a few issues for me.  Mostly, I need something like this to keep files synced between a mobile device and a desktop PC - the simplest case would be keeping a digital camera and c:\photos\ synced up.

So, is this worth using?

Comment: can someone comeup with a solution involving teracopy? i like to crc test my files immediately after i have copied them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [SyncToy v2](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) from microsoft and it is great for keeping my laptop in sync with my home pc. i got it working on windows 7 but i am yet to test it on the RC version. Using my netbook i also managed to get it to push files instead of fetching which was weird.

I find it quite adequate but very narrow in cofiguration. i could do with a product that can give you finer control and automatic sync on connection or constant sync on changes. I think for my needs, i require something scriptable to give me finer control.

Comment: SyncToy can be called from the command line, so it can be put into a batch file.  That would meet my definition of "scriptable".

Comment: For the auto sync and/or constant sync you want DropBox.  It keeps a copy on their server, but does bulletproof sync.

Comment: @tomjedrz i don't wnt my stuff on the interweb. does it do workgroups? can it work without the intertubes?

Answer (score 4):

It works ok, but it's not enterprise grade.  I have a couple of scheduled batch files that use robocopy, it works great.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Answer (score 2):

Try Windows Live Sync.
http://gofrom.us/14EA

Comment: dude, why does my data have to go through the tubes to get from one pc to the one just next to it?

Comment: That was exactly my response to Live Sync.  Not to mention the boss might mind if our IP was passing through servers in Redmond.

Comment: @jake not always both is next. I just gived an suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

[Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) is the successor to Live Sync mentioned previously.  Though it's still in beta, it's definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO ...

Yes, it works.  Not sure it is "Enterprise Grade", in that I don't believe there is a standardized way to control it (i.e group policy). I believe the CLI will allow for automating and scheduling actions.

I use robocopy inside batch files, and it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used it in the past. I haven't used it as a two-way sync, but as a one way push all my files to a fileshare as a backup, and for this purpose it works quite well inside a scheduled task. I beleive their are options to do proper two-way sync.

You just run it and setup the sync's you'd like to do, and then you can set up a scheduled task that references the syncs to run at specified times. However, you are limitted to what scheduled tasks can offer you, I always scheduled lunch time when my laptop was likely docked and I wasn't using it.